# R select row with name NA from table output

Tags: r

I am trying to print the contents of a 'table' in a custom row order as such:

make table

```
t <- table(c('a','a','b','b','c',NA),rep(1:2,each=3), useNA='ifany')
```

print contents

```
t[c('c','a','b'),]
```

But now I want to also select (as the last row) the row with rowname == NA.

If I do this:

```
t[c('c','a','b','<NA>'),]
```

or
    t[c('c','a','b',NA),]

I get

> Error in t[c("c", "a", "b", NA), ] : subscript out of bounds

or

> Error in t[c("c", "a", "b", "<NA>"), ] : subscript out of bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will free you from specifying `NA` rows manually:

```
narows <- is.na(rownames(t))
t[narows,]
# Test code
> t <- table(c('a','a','b','b','c',NA),rep(1:2,each=3), useNA='ifany')
> t

       1 2
  a    2 0
  b    1 1
  c    0 1
  <NA> 0 1
> narows <- is.na(rownames(t))
> narows
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
> t[narows,]
1 2 
0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh found the solution myself

```
t[match(c('c','a','b',NA),rownames(t)),]
```

As I was finalizing my question. Maybe someone has a better trick though?